# Typehead js live search not working in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a products site and a search box to search products in codeigniter.

my view file:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="typeahead" placeholder="Search Product."  style="height:32px; margin: 25px 0px;"  >
```

and my java script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //alert('hi');
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        //alert('%QUERY');
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'<?php echo base_url('user/search').'/'?>%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
```

my controller function:

```
function search()
{
    $key=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $array = array();

    $query = $this->general->search($key);
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
      $array[] = $row->pr_name;
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

when i use hardcode the links as `http:/localhost/products/user/search/dairymilk` it works.. but it doesn't work when i type in the textbox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first change `$('input.typeahead') to  $('input[name="typeahead"]')` there is no any class like typeahead.

```
remote:"<?php echo base_url('user/search').'/'?>"+$(this).val().
```

Even after you have any errors check in console whether your typeahead is loading or not. You can't alert `alert('%QUERY');` it will give error.